# How to disable the title field on the node edit form?

Tags: 8, nodes, forms

How can I hide or disable the title field on the node edit form?

If I do so from the content type Manage form display tab (`admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME/form-display`), then I get some integrity constraint errors in the log.

So I don't want to show default title field in Node edit form. If I hide the title field normally like other fields. Got white screen after node creation. And log says title field can't be null .... and so on ...

Comment: Are you looking for [`Node::setTitle`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AsetTitle/8.2.x) ?

Comment: @JimmyKom Thanks for comment. let me rephrase, I don't want to show default title field in Node edit form. If I hide the title field normally like other fields. Got white screen after node creation. And log says title field can't be null .... and so on ...

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.2.x) function to alter any form (including node edit form) and disable **Title** field. Check sample code below:

```
use Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem;

function [MODULE_NAME]_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'node_[CONTENT_TYPE]_edit_form':
      $form['title']['#disabled'] = 'disabled';
      break;
  }
}
```

If you're altering only one form you can check [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x) function and change **FORM_ID** with **node_[CONTENT_TYPE]_edit_form** where CONTENT_TYPE is your node type form.

### EDIT :

To automatically set node title without allowing user to see title field, you can use [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) Module. The module is in dev version for D8, but we can give it a try if functioning properly.

If don't want to use [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) module, you can try doing same with custom code, check sample code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22798033/377342)

Comment: Thanks but disabling the field is not a problem. It seems drupal core don't allow to create node without title. How you will address this error from DB `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {node_field_data}`

Comment: Ok, so basically you don't want to show title field neither on add nor edit node content and allow users to create content, right? If yes, check out this module [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) if this helps. The module is currently in its dev version.

Comment: that is in dev for D8. not sure safe to use...

Comment: If the [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) module doesn't work, you can try sample code given on this link [Auto fill Drupal 8 title?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22798033/377342).

Comment: Yes, you're right. Normally using dev version is not preferred or suggested, but if we don't have any other solution or alternate way we can give it a try.

Comment: In fact I was using similar thing for now just curious for better solution coz storing some thing which don't need . Any way thanks

Comment: @Yogesh you can edit your answer as well.

Comment: @MudassarAli, we must need to store node title as it is required for every node as per Drupal node Structure. We'll have to use some default value if not entered by user.

Comment: @JimmyKo, I've updated my answer with above comments. Thanks

Comment: How are you identifying nodes in the administrative interface if they do not have a title? How are you accounting for meta data and such? This is pretty unorthodox, just saying. Best to fill in some value, somehow.

Comment: @kevin very true. Example use case content type could be `person` with first name and last name fields. Here editor don't need to enter title.  But what we could use hook and enter first name and last name in title field for administrative purpose.  This could be nice solution. What I think.

Answer (score 4):

tl;dr: **Specify a default title, and don't allow the user to change it.**

The D7→D8 [change records](https://www.drupal.org/node/2231763) state:

> **node_type->has_title removed in favor of entity form displays**
>
> Now that it is possible to configure the behavior of the node title
>   widget using Entity form displays, the special flag to hide the title
>   form element for nodes is no longer needed.
>
> To hide the title for a certain node type, use the "Manage form
>   display" UI or hide it with a snippet like the following:
>
> ```
> $form_display = entity_get_form_display('node', 'article', 'default');
> $form_display->removeComponent('title');
> $form_display->save();
> ```

After reading that, I tried a few ways of doing it. Only the last one works, so this answer should serve as a warning of what *not* to try:

### Edit the entity_form_display config

If it is your own module, edit `core.entity_form_display.node.my_content_type.default.yml` and remove the `title` key from `content`. This works for fields, but if I remove the title or any of the other default things like promoted, created, etc., they are still displayed on the form at `/node/add/my_content_type`.

### Modify the entity_form_display in code

Add this code to `my_module_install` :

```
$form_display = entity_get_form_display('node', 'my_content_type', 'default');
$form_display->removeComponent('title');
$form_display->save();
```

This works visually, but there are three problems with this solution:
- It still causes the integrity constraint errors you refer to.
- It causes the config in the database to override the config in the file at install time, which is a bad idea, IMHO.
- `entity_get_form_display` is deprecated

### Hide it in the entity_form_display config

Hide it, but don't remove it. In `core.entity_form_display.node.my_content_type.default.yml`:

```
hidden:
  title: false
```

By trial and error, I found the logic to be reversed here. This, too, causes the integrity constraint errors you refer to.

### Hide it using CSS

I tried this, and it seems that empty strings are also disallowed for the title. So you either have to create your own entity type, which reimplements most of the code from the core node module, or...

### The only working solution I could find

Specify a default title, and don't allow the user to change it.

```
function my_module_form_node_my_content_type_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['title']['#disabled'] = 'disabled';
  $form['title']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value'] = 'none';
}
```

You could change `none` to `my_module`, a timestamp, or your favourite brand of peanut butter.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solve this issue in a project. At this moment [Automatic Entity Label](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel) don't have a Drupal 8 version, if you [see the code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/auto_entitylabel/tree/) you will find only a info.yml file.

You always need to set the title, so in the creation of the entity you set the title.

```
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_node_create(NodeInterface $node) {
  switch ($node->getType()) {
    case 'CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME':
      $node->title = 'Date: ' . date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
      break;
  }
}
```

And the other part is hide the title in the node form, to do this you can use:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  //With this you will know your form_id (see in the next function YOUR_FORM_ID)
  dpm($form_id);
}
```

And in this hook you will hide the title, with this you do the trick

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_form_YOUR_FORM_ID_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['title']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the automatic node title module. This will allow you to set the node title to whatever you want in the content type configuration, but will not display the field on add or edit.

Answer (score 0):

I found the title to be useful in many ways in the layout builder:
- Show content preview
- Use it as block Id

My solution generates automatic titles by using the block type title and counting the number of blocks from the same type.

```
function [module]_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id === 'layout_builder_add_block') {
    // Get the blocks plugins id counter.
    $bundle = $form['settings']['block_form']['#block']->bundle();
    $plugin_id = 'inline_block:' . $bundle;

    // Get the blocks plugins id count array.
    if ($node = $form_state->getTemporary()['gathered_contexts']['layout_builder.entity']->getContextData()->getEntity()) {
      $block_count = 0;
      foreach ($node->layout_builder__layout as $section) {
        $components = $section->section->getComponents();
        foreach ($components as $block) {
          if ($plugin_id === $block->getPluginId()) {
            $block_count += 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // If not exist start from 0.
    // Insert default title.
    $form['settings']['label']['#default_value'] = t('%title-%title_id', [
      '%title' => $form['settings']['admin_label']['#plain_text'],
      '%title_id' => $block_count,
    ]);
    // Change title description.
    $form['settings']['label']['#title'] = t('Block id');
    $form['settings']['label']['#description'] = t('Automatic id generator. Can be modified by user but must be unique.');
    // Update and hide display title checkbox.
    // $form['settings']['label_display']['#default_value'] = FALSE;
    // $form['settings']['label_display']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }

  if ($form_id === 'layout_builder_update_block') {
    // Change title description.
    $form['settings']['label']['#title'] = t('Block id');
    $form['settings']['label']['#description'] = t('Automatic id generator. Can be modified by user but must be unique.');
    // Update and hide display title checkbox.
    // $form['settings']['label_display']['#default_value'] = FALSE;
    // $form['settings']['label_display']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}

/**
 * HOOK_preprocess_block.
 */
function [module]_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  // Add id into block.
  $label = qfcc_structure_normaliseLabelToId($variables['label']);
  if (!$label) {
    $label = rand(100, 999);
  }
  $variables['attributes']['id'] = 'block-' . $label;
}

function [module]_normaliseLabelToId($text) {
  if (!$text) {
    return NULL;
  }

  $text = trim(strtolower($text));
  $text = str_replace(' ', '-', $text);
  $text = str_replace('_', '-', $text);
  $text = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9\-]/', '', $text);
  return $text ?? NULL;
}
```

[image]
[image]